# Update the JTable when I click button

Tags: java, swing, jtable

In My application I have add a JTabel and using a setCellRender method I add a button column to the table as follows.

```
    jTable1 = new JTable();
    String[] columnNames = {"Module", "Status", "Connectivity", "Action", "Start Time", "Logs"};
    data = getServerExecutions();
    model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
             return true;
        }
    };
    jTable1.setModel(model);

    jTable1.getColumn("Action").setCellRenderer(new ButtonRenderer());
    jTable1.getColumn("Action").setCellEditor(new ButtonEditor(new JCheckBox()));
```

getSeverExecution Method load data from database table.
When I click on Action button database get updated without any problems. 
Also there is a Refresh button in the window. Within the action performed method I reassign data to variabel data and refresh the table.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           data = getServerExecutions();
           model.fireTableDataChanged();

        }
```

but table data is not reloaded. Only when I close and open the window it get updated. what is wrong here?? Can some one pls help me..

Comment: Actually what i want to do is assign new data to 'data' and redraw the table by using it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
data = getServerExecutions();
```

Does not set the data in the table.  It just sets the data variable to point to the new data.  You need to update the `TableModel` instead.  To do this either:

- Call the appropriate methods on your model
- Create a new model and set that model in the JTable
- or extend DefaultTableModel and create a way to update the data that the model runs off of

Seeing you recreate the data each time, I would just select the second choice.